# Big oh and big Omega?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have question is about big oh and big omega

if $f(n)$ is $\Omega(n^2)$ is $f(n)$ $O(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The first means that for some $n_0$ and a positive $c$ it is $f(n) \ge c n^2$; the second one says that for some $n_0'$ and a positive $c'$ it is $f(n) \le c' n^2$. For example, $n^3 = \Omega(n^2)$ but $n^3 \ne O(n^2)$; while $n \ne \Omega(n^2)$ but $n = O(n^2)$.

Comment: Great answer i totally understand it now

Comment: Just one more quick question can $f(x) = 2$ be $O(n)$ or $\Omega(n)$